# Can't branch from the TortoiseSVN repo browser

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, branching-and-merging

I need to branch from a tag and I would ideally like to do it through the repository browser. The problem is that there is is no `Branch/tag` option in the context menu of the repo browser.

The reason for this is that, if I do it via Windows Explorer, I need to `svn update` the tags folder, which can take quite a while. This can be mitigated by doing an `svn checkout` of the particular tag, but this can still take some time, and is (slightly) more work that just doing it through the repo browser.

Does anyone know why this command is not available in the repo browser? I think that the `Copy to...` option might essentially do the same thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you said I also would use the `copy to` function. Checkout and create a new branch is the same and will do what you want but `copy to` should also work considering the information from [svnbook.red-bean.com](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.6/svn.ref.svn.c.copy.html)

[image: The <code>Copy to...</code> function is below <code>Copy to working copy...</code> and above <code>Show properties</code> for me.]

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. As per the book, doing a branch via the command line is done via svn copy.

Comment: In my opinion naming and synonyms in svn are sometimes a little bit confusing :-)